# Node.js module that inspects DOM elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I'm using [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), a headless browser mostly for testing purposes. It creates a browser object that once the function `visit()` is called allows you to play with the DOM of a given page. However, I wasn't able to get it to that extent. It looks like there is an issue with the parser used in zombie. 
Here is the error:

`User/murf/Documents/workspace/node_code/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/html5/lib/html5/tokenizer.js:62`

Has anyone found a similar issue? If so, is there a way to go around it? Or maybe is there is another node module that does similar work? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you list for the error is just where the error occurred. Surely there's also an error *message*?

Comment: @Crowder   yes there is. I thought it was too long to actually show it. But here is a part --> Error: undefined: attribute name: "
    at Object.createAttribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZombieJS and other web testing tools is built on [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) which is really easy to use just like Zombie. However the thing is you don't have stuff like "type" but you could easily simulate it in JSDOM, example:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env("http://nodejs.org/dist/", [
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
], function(errors, window) {
  console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length, "nodejs releases!");
});
```

That is a code sample from JSDOM, so if you want for example to simulate type you'll have to trigger for instance `keydown` manually

```
$('someInput')
              .val('x')
              .keydown();
```

That will somehow simulate `type('x')`, for ex. for google search that will trigger getting the suggestion box.
However in order to properly simulate it, you have to create a keydown event with keyCode and everything.

I'm working on a new headless browser for Node called [htmlnode](https://github.com/amasad/htmlnode), but its still work in progress, expected to be usable next week, and its built on top of [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Other options:

- [SodaJS](http://sodajs.com/)
- [Tobi](https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi) (headless, built on top of JSDOM)
- [JellyFish](https://github.com/admc/jellyfish)